# How to change SharpShell Icon Overlay handler name to contain space in registry to take priority over Dropbox and other programs?

Tags: c#, com, sharpshell

I want to change Sharpshell Icon over handler name so, my handlers will take precedence over other handlers. I noted that Dropbox and Google Drive use space in their handler names so, they take precedence over my sharpshell handlers but i can't add space to my sharpshell handler names as c# compiler doesn't allow space in class names; also, i added the attribute DisplayName but nothing happened.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[DisplayName(" Test")]
public class SyncedIconOverlayHandler : SharpIconOverlayHandler
{}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename you ShellExtension manually. And there is actually no way to do it using SharpShell. And, also my advice, use fews spaces. Some software is already using more then 4 spaces in name of OverlayIcon!

Here are some ways, how to rename you ShellExtension in registry: https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell/issues/93